Why aren't non-ranged STL algorithms constrained with concepts in C++20?
Take std::sort and std::ranges::sort as examples, the iterator class in std::ranges::sort is constrained with the concept std::random_access_iterator:
template< std::random_access_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
          class Comp = ranges::less, class Proj = std::identity >
requires std::sortable<I, Comp, Proj>
constexpr I
    sort( I first, S last, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {} );

But std::sort is not:
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );

Why isn't std::sort (and all non-ranged algorithms) constrained?
A related question: What is the difference between std::fill_n and std::ranges::fill_n?

Because std::sort predates concepts

IMHO: C++ is a pay for what you use language.  If you want type constraints and concepts then pay for it by using ranges.  If not then keep on using <algorithm> and don't pay for the extra compile time doing the constraining.

C++20 introduced both std::ranges and concepts, so gave an obvious opportunity/motivation for design/specification of std::ranges to exploit concepts. Older algorithms, that accept pairs of iterators (like std::sort()) predate concepts, and were simply not updated in C++20.  This is typical of how the C++ standard (and most standards with a formal governing process) evolve - it takes time/effort to update older features to use newer features and that increases risk of breaking something.  Future proposals (dependent on time/effort) might or might not change this

@NathanOliver, but was the "pay for what you use" ever meant to apply to compilation time? If a constrained std::sort would, for valid inputs, produce the same binary code as the present non-constrained version, why should I care about the increase in compilation time? Maybe the reason for not constraining old algos is backward compatibility, in which case, I suppose some constraint could break at compile-time code that was legit in older standards, and some would break code that was not legit in the first place, and happened to work just because of UB.

I guess constraints that would cause the latter type of breakage could be added, in principle.

It is "constrained", just not in the concept sense:
[algorithm.requirements]p(4.7)

If an algorithm's template parameter is named RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator1, or RandomAccessIterator2, the template argument shall meet the Cpp17RandomAccessIterator requirements ([random.access.iterators]) if it is required to be a mutable iterator, or model random_access_iterator ([iterator.concept.random.access]) otherwise.

This "shall" requirement could be tested with a static_assert in your C++ standard library (and has always been able to). It's just a quality-of-implementation issue if the standard library implementors look for stuff that isn't actually used.
This is different from a concept constrained parameter, where the function does not participate in overload resolution.
template<typename T>
concept is_std_sortable = requires(T t) { std::sort(t, t); };
template<typename T>
concept is_std_ranges_sortable = requires(T t) { std::ranges::sort(t, t); };

static_assert(is_std_sortable<int>);
static_assert(!is_std_ranges_sortable<int>);

You can see how this would be necessary with the multiple overloads (range or iterator pair) and default arguments to select the correct function when called.
It isn't necessary for the non-ranges algorithms, which only have a single overload. The ones that have multiple overloads take an execution policy as the first argument and the second overload is essentially concept constrained ([algorithms.parallel.overloads]p4)

Maybe stupid question: What is the this in this would be necessary with the multiple overloads? Doing what, is necessary?

@Enlico If there were no constraints then std::ranges::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()) would be ambiguous with the iterator pair overload or the range overload with the second argument being the comparator. A similar problem happened with the iterator pair constructor of std::string competing with the size_type, CharT overload (#10 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string )

I think I've understood the original point, but I don't quite get the analogy, though, because those two overloads you mention of std::string are not ambiguous, are they?

This is correct, but this answer is more about the mechanics internal to std::range than why non-ranges algorithms are not requirement-constrained.

@Enlico char count = 12; std::string(count, 'c');  // Would have called the two iterator overload. Or int count = 12; int char = 'c'; std::string(count, char);

@alfC The three points are: non-ranges algorithms do have "constraints", non-ranges algorithms don't need constraints like std::ranges:: ones, in situations where non-ranges algorithms would need constraints they basically do

@Artyer, I still don't get what you mean. char count = 12; std::string(count, 'c'); calls the size_type, CharT ctor, so what do you mean by whould have called the two iterator overload? In which case? The case that size_type was just the name of an unconstrained template parameter?

@Enlico In case the iterator pair constructor wasn't constrained: https://godbolt.org/z/xzr1YEe47

Of course there are practical and historical reasons; but if one wants to think of an after-the-fact-reason:
You would break otherwise a lot of code; range-style requirements are more constrained that what you can imagine.
There is a lot of code in the wild (custom iterators) that almost work by accident with algorithms and definitely do not compile with std::ranges algorithms.
Take for example a common requirement in std::ranges such as indirectly_writable https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_writable .
I can bet that almost all non-trivial iterators written before Concepts will actually not fulfill all the constraints imposed.

I wonder if many of the "almost work by accident" cases are actually UB in the first place.

For comparison, ranges requires "whole" comparaison set, whereas old algorithms only require < and/or ==. Using complete concepts would break code, providing incomplete concepts seems bad.

@Enlico , it is not UB in the normal runtime sense. It is at a more semantic level. Like Jarod said, suppose a type defines op<, and op==. For classic STL this is enough to make the type ordered. you can even leave undefined op> and op!= or even define then in a independent (inconsistent) way. STL claasic will not notice. However STL ranges could complain about the inconsistent or undefined operations even if you know the implementation doesn’t use them!

@alfC, that's why I said many and not all. The case you talk about was legit code, and still is because old algos have not been constrained. If old algos were constrained, that code would break at compile time. I wonder if there's a sunset of constraints that, if added, would only break (at compile time and/or run time?) code that exhibited UB in the first place. Maybe I'm just saying BS.

No, I think your concern is valid. and yes there can be UB but it is more like “library” UB in the sense that custom implementations of iterators may work with some implementations of STL and not with others or that slight changes in the implementation can lead to either things not compiling, given different or incorrect results or, unlikely but possible, UB as you said. UB is always possible, what I am saying is that is not something particular to imposing constrains.
